# VBA MS-Word legacy form field calculation

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have 3 legacy form fields, named text1, text2, and text3. My sample code is:

```
Option Explicit

Public a as integer
Public b as integer
Public c as integer

Sub TextA()
  If ActiveDocument.FormFields("text1").Result = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must specify a number. If none, enter a zero."
  End If
  a = ActiveDocument.FormFields("text1").Result  
End Sub

Sub TextB()
  If ActiveDocument.FormFields("text2").Result = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must specify a number. If none, enter a zero."
  End If
  b = ActiveDocument.FormFields("text2").Result
End Sub

Sub CalculateC()
  c = a + b
End Sub
```

Now text1 and text2 run the 1st two subs respectively on exit (set in their property menu)...I want text3 to automatically display c. I'm thinking I could use the form field property "Calculate" or run the sub (run on entry perhaps?) - or a combination of both, but cannot quite get it working. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched some more and discovered how the Calculations work in fields... I check "Calculate on Exit" for text1 & text2, and select "Calculation" as the type on text3, with the expression "=text1+text2" and no VBA is required. I then can have a macro to record the results of text1 + text2 run on exit in text2 if I need to capture that variable for later use.